# Making a grocery basket

Tags: java

So i'm trying to create a program that allows the user to put items inside a grocery basket.

- Step 1:Users should be able to add a grocery item with the name and the price.
- Step 2:No duplicate name should be added on the basket
- Step 3:Users should be able to remove a grocery item given the name.
- Step 4:Users should be able to see all the contents of the basket.

I know i'm almost done, but I'm stuck with step step 3 and 4, any suggestions?

this is my code

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner myReader = new Scanner(System.in);    

    while (true) {
    System.out.println("What would you want to do today?");
    System.out.println("(A)dd grocery item\n(R)emove grocery item\n(S)ee all items"); 
    System.out.println("Enter Command: ");
    String toDo = myReader.nextLine();

        if (toDo.equals("A")) {
            System.out.print("New Item Name: ");
            String grocery = myReader.nextLine();
            GroceryPackage grocery1 = new GroceryPackage();
            grocery1.addGrocery(grocery);
            System.out.print("New Item Price: ");
            String groceryPrice = myReader.nextLine();
            grocery1.addGrocery(groceryPrice);
            System.out.println("Added new item Succesfully!");

        }
        if (toDo.equals("R")) {
            System.out.print("Name of the Item you want to Remove: ");
            String removeItem = myReader.nextLine();
            removeItem.removeGrocery(grocery);


        }
        if (toDo.equals("S")) {
            System.out.print(GroceryPackage);
        }

        System.out.println("Thanks!");
    }


}


}

public class GroceryPackage {
private String addGrocery;
private boolean groceryPrice;
private String removeGrocery;
private String grocery1;


public void setGrocery1(String grocery1) {
    this.grocery1 = grocery1;

}

public void setListofGrocery(ArrayList<String> listofGrocery) {
    this.listofGrocery = listofGrocery;
}
private ArrayList<String> listofGrocery;

public GroceryPackage(String addGrocery, boolean groceryPrice) {
    this.addGrocery = addGrocery;
    this.groceryPrice = groceryPrice;                
}

public GroceryPackage() {
    this.listofGrocery = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void addGrocery(String grocery){
    if (!this.listofGrocery.contains(grocery)){
        this.listofGrocery.add(grocery);
    }
}

public void printGrocery(){
    for (String food: this.listofGrocery){
        System.out.println(food);
    }
}

public void removeGrocery(){
    this.listofGrocery.clear();
}

public void setAddGrocery(String addGrocery) {
    this.addGrocery = addGrocery;
}

public void setGroceryPrice(boolean groceryPrice) {
    this.groceryPrice = groceryPrice;
}

public void setRemoveGrocery(String removeGrocery) {
    this.removeGrocery = removeGrocery;
}

public String getAddGrocery() {
    return addGrocery;
}

public boolean getGroceryPrice() {
    return groceryPrice;
}

public String getRemoveGrocery() {
    return removeGrocery;
}
}
```

and it should run like this:

```
What would you want to do today?
(A)dd grocery item
(R)emove grocery item?
(S)ee all items?
A
New Item name:
Carrot
New Item price:
100
Added new item successfully
What would you want to do today?
(A)dd grocery item
(R)emove grocery item?
(S)ee all items?
A
New Item name:
Pineapple
New Item price:
20
Added new item successfully
What would you want to do today?
(A)dd grocery item
(R)emove grocery item?
(S)ee all items?
R
Name of item you want to remove:
Pineapple
Removed new item successfully
What would you want to do today?
(A)dd grocery item
(R)emove grocery item?
(S)ee all items?
S
Carrot , P100.0

What would you want to do today?
(A)dd grocery item
(R)emove grocery item?
(S)ee all items?
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Item 3 is as straightforward as it sounds: find and remove. What problem (more specific than "I'm stuck") do you encounter?

Comment: What's in your code? You have to formulate your problem in specific terms, such as "Why do I have IndexOutOfBounds exceptions when I try to remove the element: <some code>?" . Otherwise, it's your exercise, and you should do this by yourself. We are somewhat happy to help you with technical problems, not with solving HW for you. Somewhat, because extremely basic questions are also not appreciated.

Comment: You have to keep added items in a global variable (may be in a `java.util.Set`). Currently your "add" code does not do that. In `grocery1.addGrocery(grocery);` `grocery1` is just a local variable, which will not be available after you exit that `if` block.

Comment: In your "remove" code you have `String removeItem = myReader.nextLine(); removeItem.removeGrocery(grocery);`. `removeItem` is a `String` object. So, there is no `removeGrocery()` method in `String` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are too many things wrong with this program to make this a simple fix. You really need to scale back your program and work on making it as simple as possible. Your program is far larger than it needs to be.

You cannot have two public classes in the same file. Your "GroceryPackage" class doesn't seem to provide anything you can't do with the methods of your ArrayList variable "listofGrocery" itself, other than keeping track of prices (which it doesn't do). It unnecessarily complicates the program.

You could try just removing it's "public" keyword altogether, or make it a private or static inner class of Main. However, I would suggest just getting rid of it. I really don't think you need it.

Technically, you haven't achieved step 2 yet. There is nothing preventing duplicate values in your ArrayList. I would use a `HashMap<String, Double>` instead. This will allow you to store the "groceries" as strings with their prices as Double values.

You can use "getter" and "setter" methods in GroceryPackage to obtain, modify, and return your ArrayList, obtain the variable directly with `GroceryPackage.listofGrocery` (listofGrocery won't work with this if the variable is private), or just make it an attribute of your Main class. The last is the simplest option.

I noticed you never actually initialize the "listofGrocery" variable as an attribute of "GroceryPackage".

Stylistically, "listofGrocery" should be "listOfGrocery".

You don't use the "grocery1" attribute in GroceryList.

**To solve step two, No duplicate name should be added on the basket**

Either iterate through all the values in the data structure, or use a data structure that either throws an exception or returns a predictable sort of value if the value being added has a duplicate inside. Make sure whatever you do, you don't replace any values that are already inside the data structure.

**To solve step three, "users should be able to remove a grocery item given the name."**

You try to give your "removeGrocery()" method an argument even though it doesn't take any. Also, the clear() method removes *all* the values in the entire ArrayList. Take a close look at the methods available for whichever data structure you choose.

**For step four, "users should be able to see all the contents of the basket."**

Iterate through all the contents of the basket.

**To sum up.**

I mostly avoided giving you the outright answers to your program's issues. However, hopefully you can take what I've said and realize where you went wrong. There are actually thousands of different ways you can get your program to meet the requirements. Be sure to *carefully* read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) online. They are *invaluable*. Finally, I noticed you never use any loops in your program. These are a novice programmer's best friend. Learn to love them.